# My program does not make me what I want to do

Tags: c++

I'm starting with conditionals in C + +

I need a program to give me the cost of computers, and the program returns 1 for me just everything.

Help, please.

thanks

```
#include <iostream>

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

bool CostComputers(int computadores)
{
    if (computadores < 20){ computadores * 3000000; }
    else if (computadores > 20 && computadores < 40){ computadores * 2740000; }
    else if (computadores >= 40){ computadores * 2150000; }
    else {
        return "error";
    }
}


int main()
{
    int computadores;
    bool CostComputers = (computadores);
    printf("Calculate the cost of the computer...");
    printf("Enter the number of computers...", computadores);
    scanf("%d", &computadores);
    CostComputers = (computadores);
    printf("El costo es ... %d", CostComputers);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bit heavy on the enter key but not so clever with either the spacebar/tab key

Comment: Your variable `bool CostComputers` is hiding the function with the same name.  You're never calling the function.  And when you pass a boolean variable to `printf`, you get either `0` or `1`.

Comment: This does not even compile, the function does not always return a value

Comment: @SJuan76: True, the braces are messed up.  Here's the version that compiles: http://ideone.com/gXz1jv

Comment: @BenVoigt My bad, I thought C/C++ forced to return a value for all paths, I googled and found it is only a warning... Another reason to stick with Java/C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be kind lost how c++ works, so I won't bother trying to explain, try it out yourself and examine how it works. You should really get a C++ book from somewhere which explains everything from the beginning through detailed examples.

```
#include <iostream>

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int CostComputers(int computadores)
{
    if (computadores < 20) {
        return computadores * 3000000;
    }
    else if (computadores > 20 && computadores < 40) {
        return computadores * 2740000;
    }
    else if (computadores >= 40) {
        return computadores * 2150000;
    }

    // Every other case
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int computadores;
    printf("Calculate the cost of the computer...");
    printf("Enter the number of computers...");
    scanf("%d", &computadores);
    int computer_price = CostComputers(computadores);
    if (computer_price != 0) {
        printf("El costo es ... %d", computer_price);
    }
    else {
        printf("Invalid computer amount");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't need to buy exactly 20 computers. But seriously, you've reinforced his impression that SO is a code writing service and helped avoid having to understand anything for another week, until the next homework assignment when he's even further behind and more lost. A fix without explanation is not helping anyone. Honestly, he needs to learn to fix it himself with just a few hints.

Comment: If he does not care about understanding, explaining it would be nothing but a waste of time. Building a castle of air will not work, thats one thing that he'll sure learn.